# mysql ignores where statement

Tags: php, mysql, debian, magento-1.7

I use this query to get all sales from yesterday. To export this somewhere.
Since there are a lot of *cancelled, pending payment, processing and so on*, I thought to export only the ones that are completed.

But somehow mysql just ignoes the fist where restriction.
I get all the sales all the time. It doesn't matter what i write in. 
It only has to be a state that was used yesterday.

```
$sql = '

SELECT
        sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id,
        sales_flat_order_grid.increment_id AS increment_id,
        sales_flat_order_grid.quote_id AS quote_id,
        sales_flat_order_grid.store_name AS store_name,
        sales_flat_order_grid.created_at AS created_at,
        sales_flat_order_grid.billing_name AS billing_name,
        sales_flat_order_grid.payment_method AS payment_method,
        sales_flat_order_grid.grand_total AS grand_total,
        sales_order_status.label AS status,
        sales_flat_order_item.sku AS sku,
        sales_flat_order_item.name AS name,
        sales_flat_order_item.price_incl_tax AS price_incl_tax,
        sales_flat_order_item.product_options AS product_options,
        sales_flat_order_payment.additional_information AS additional_information

FROM
        sales_flat_order_grid,
        sales_order_status,
        sales_flat_order_item,
        sales_flat_order_payment

WHERE
        sales_flat_order_grid.status = "Complete"
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.entity_id
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at >= "' . $date . ' 00:00:00"
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at <= "' . $date . ' 23:59:59"

ORDER BY
        sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id DESC

';
```

Comment: This should work completely fine - are you sure your problem isn't elsewhere? Have you tried switching out `'`'s with `"`'s and opposite?

Comment: no, i'll give this a try

Comment: Can't see a cause for the issue you have, but you do seem to have an inadvertent cross join (no JOIN condition specified for the join to sakes_order_status)

Comment: @h2ooooooo no unfortunatly not. but it would be very cheesy if it would be so^^

Comment: Tip: You can do `from tablename as something` and then reference that table using `something`. Makes for tidier queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting yourself up for disaster when you write queries like this:

```
FROM
    sales_flat_order_grid,
    sales_order_status,
    sales_flat_order_item,
    sales_flat_order_payment

WHERE
    sales_flat_order_grid.status = "Complete"
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.entity_id
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at >= "' . $date . ' 00:00:00"
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at <= "' . $date . ' 23:59:59"
```

Why? Because it's too easy to miss a `JOIN` condition.

Instead, use this syntax:

```
FROM
    sales_flat_order_grid
    INNER JOIN sales_order_status ON ....
    INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_item ON sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id
    INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_payment ON sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.entity_id

WHERE
    sales_flat_order_grid.status = "Complete"
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at >= "' . $date . ' 00:00:00"
    AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at <= "' . $date . ' 23:59:59"
```

See the `....` there? It's missing a join condition and therefore it selects a **cartesian product** instead. Add the missing join condition and your results should be more in line with your expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Jack. I'm gonna use join from now on.

Answer (score 1):

There is a table named "sales_order_status" in the FROM clause, but I don't see how it joined with other tables. So I think that is the problem. You are missing a part related to sales_order_status table in JOIN clause.

So what you get currently is a **cross join** between **sales_order_status** table and the resultant table you got by joining **sales_flat_order_grid**, **sales_flat_order_item** and **sales_flat_order_payment**. Therefore you see all of order status in your query result.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem on your where is that you are expecting a column value to have two different values at the same time, maybe you want that column to have either of those value

this might work

```
WHERE
        sales_flat_order_grid.status = "Complete"
        AND (sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id
             OR sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id = sales_flat_order_payment.entity_id)
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at >= "' . $date . ' 00:00:00"
        AND sales_flat_order_grid.created_at <= "' . $date . ' 23:59:59"
```

Comment: I think we 2 have kinda the same way to think, but it's not the proper way.

Comment: @derty you are correct, I totally missed the fact he was using Joins :)